# Keyboard shortcut to switch Split View positions in macOS

Tags: macos, applescript

While in Split View in macOS, clicking the top of a window and dragging it to the left or right will fluidly switch positions of the two windows. I use this feature a lot and can't find any online information about a keyboard shortcut to do this.

Can anyone come up with an AppleScript script or solution for this without using a different window management app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK There is no native default *keyboard shortcut* to swap the *position* of *windows* in **Split View**.

AFAIK There is no native default *preference* to set a *keyboard shortcut* to swap the *position* of *windows* in **Split View**.

That said, this answer presents an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* method to *swap* the *position* of *windows* in **Split View**, which uses the *third-party utility* [**cliclick**](https://www.bluem.net/en) to perform the *mouse click and drag events* necessary to accomplish the task, while using the *third-party utility* [**displayplacer**](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) to provide Display resolutions along with which Display is the primary Display in multiple Display scenarios.

**This currently works with:**

- One or two Displays max.
- Primary Display on left or right.
- **Split View** on left, right, or both Displays, regardless of which is the primary Display.
- **Both Displays must be aligned at their top in:** **System Preferences** > **Displays** > **Arrangement**

  - <sup>An updated *script* to handle offset alignments *may* come at a future date. (Emphasis on *may*!)</sup>

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, is used in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* with settings **Workflow receives [no input] in [any application]**, using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with settings **Shell: [/bin/zsh]** and **Pass input: [to stdin]**, using the *example* **shell script** *code*, then assigned a *keyboard shortcut* for the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

I set the *keyboard shortcut* for the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, name **Swap Split View Windows**, to: **⌥⌘/**

Note that assigning a *global keyboard shortcut* can be difficult to not step on a *keyboard shortcut* of whichever *application* has focus when the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed, and also may require adding that *application* to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** or respond to a security related dialog box (more than once).

It may be better to use any of the *third-party applications* that can handle triggering *scripts* with a *keyboard shortcut*, then it is to use an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*. I use *applications* [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) and [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) for many of my *global keyboard shortcuts*.

One reason I like using *third-party applications* to handle *script* execution and *global keyboard shortcuts* is that some of them intercept the *keyboard shortcut* before the *application* that has focus can receive it. This has its pros and cons in that if the *keyboard shortcut* is really meant for the *application* that has focus it's not received and whatever it is assigned to as a *global keyboard shortcut* triggers. Manually clicking the target menu item becomes necessary in such a case, or temporarily disabling the *third-party application*.

The bottom line here is that one just needs to remain aware of the modifications one has made to the system and what the potential conflicts may be.

**You have been warned!**

---

### *Example* **shell script** *code*:

```
#!/bin/zsh

    # Fully Qualified Pathname of 'cliclick'  
    # and 'displayplacer' binary executable,  
    # tokenized for ease of code maintenance.

click="/usr/local/bin/cliclick"
display="/usr/local/bin/displayplacer"


###########################################################
#                                                         #
# DO NOT MODIFY BELOW UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING! #
#                                                         #
###########################################################


    # Verify binary executables exist and notify if not.

if [ ! -e "${click}" ]; then
    osascript -e "display alert \"The '\" & \"${click}\" & \"' binary executable is missing!...\" as critical" >/dev/null
    exit
fi
if [ ! -e "${display}" ]; then
    osascript -e "display alert \"The '\" & \"${display}\" & \"' binary executable is missing!...\" as critical" >/dev/null
    exit
fi  

##########################################################

    #     Variables
    #
    #   click = Cliclick Command Line Utility
    # display = Displayplacer Command Line Utility
    #    ditf = Display Info Temp File
    #      dc = Display Count
    #      md = Mirror Displays [Off|On]
    #     pdw = Primary Display Width   
    #     sdw = Secondary Display Width
    #   pdoyc = Primary Display Origin Y Coordinate
    #   sdoyc = Secondary Display Origin Y Coordinate
    #     tdw = Total Display Width
    #     dyc = Drag Y Coordinate
    #    doyc = Display Offset Y Coordinate
    #   mryco = Mouse Return Y Coordinate Offset
    #     efo = Easing Factor Option of cliclick command    
    #       c = x coordinate of cliclick c command
    #      dd = x coordinate of cliclick dd command
    #     wm1 = Wait Milliseconds of cliclick w command
    #      xy = Current Mouse Coordinates
    #       x = Horizontal Mouse Coordinate
    #       y = Vertical Mouse Coordinate   


ditf="/private/tmp/display.ssvw"
"${display}" list > "$ditf"
dc="$(awk '/current mode/ {i++} END { print i }' "$ditf" )"
md="$(system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Mirror:/{print $2; exit}')"
pdw="$(awk '/current mode/ { sub(/res:/, "" ,$3); sub(/x[0-9]+/, "", $3); print $3; exit }' "$ditf")"
sdw="$(awk '/current mode/ { v = $3 } END { sub(/res:/, "", v); sub(/x[0-9]+/, "", v); print v }' "$ditf")"
pdoyc="$(awk '/Origin:/ { sub(/\(.*,/, "", $2 ); sub(/\)/, "", $2 ); print $2; exit }' "$ditf")"
sdoyc="$(awk '/Origin:/ { v = $2 } END { sub(/\(.*,/, "", v); sub(/\)/, "", v); print v }' "$ditf")"
tdw="$(( pdw + sdw ))"
dyc="25"
doyc="$(( sdoyc + dyc ))"
mryco="200"
efo="0"
c="70"
dd="${c}"
wm1="125"
xy="$("${click}" p)"
[[ $xy =~ ([-0-9]+)(,)([-0-9]+) ]] && x="${match[1]}" y="${match[3]}"
[[ $y -lt "${mryco}" ]] && xy="${x},${mryco}"

##########################################################


cleanup() {
    # Delete Display Info Temp File
    # Using Z Shell Modifiers Syntax
    cd "${ditf:h}" || exit 
    rm "${ditf:t}" 
}

if [[ ${dc} -eq 1 ]]; then
            # Display Count equals one.
    "${click}" -e ${efo} c:${c},0 w:${wm1} dd:${c},${dyc} dm:${pdw},${dyc} du:${pdw},${dyc} m:${xy}
    cleanup 
    exit
fi

if [[ ${dc} -gt 1 ]] && [[ ${md} == On ]]; then
        # Display Count is greater than one and Mirror Displays is On.  
    "${click}" -e ${efo} c:${c},0 w:${wm1} dd:${c},${dyc} dm:${pdw},${dyc} du:${pdw},${dyc} m:${xy}
    cleanup 
    exit
fi

if [[ ${dc} -gt 2 ]] && [[ ${md} == Off ]]; then
        # Only coded for maximum of two displays at this time. Further development may come.
    osascript -e 'display alert "As currently coded this only works with maximum of two displays!"' >/dev/null
    cleanup
    exit
fi  

    # Display Count equals two and Mirror Displays is Off.

if [[ ${pdoyc} -eq 0 ]] && [[ ${sdoyc} -eq 0 ]]; then

        # Both displays are aligned at the top.

    if [[ ${x} =~ ^\-[0-9]+$ ]]; then

            # SD is on Left when "${x}" is negative and SV is on the Left.

            # Primary Display: Right
            # Secondary Display: Left, with Tops Aligned
            # Split View on Secondary Display: Left

        c="$(( -sdw + c ))"
        dd="${c}"
        "${click}" -e ${efo} c:=${c},${sdoyc} w:${wm1} dd:=${dd},${doyc} dm:=-1,${doyc} du:=-1,${doyc} m:${xy}
        cleanup
        exit
    fi

    if [[ ${x} -gt ${pdw} ]]; then

            # PD is on the Left when "${x}" is greater than PD width.

            # Primary Display: Left
            # Secondary Display: Right, with Tops Aligned
            # Split View on Secondary Display: Right

        c="$(( c + pdw ))"
        dd="${c}"
        "${click}" -e ${efo} c:${c},${sdoyc} w:${wm1} dd:${dd},${doyc} dm:${tdw},${doyc} du:${tdw},${doyc} m:${xy}

    else

            # Primary Display: [Right|Left]
            # Secondary Display: [Left|Right], with Tops Aligned
            # Split View on Primary Display: [Right|Left]

        "${click}" -e ${efo} c:${c},${sdoyc} w:${wm1} dd:${dd},${doyc} dm:${tdw},${doyc} du:${tdw},${doyc} m:${xy}

    fi

else
        # As currently coded the displays must be aligned, and notify if not. Further development may come.
    osascript -e "display alert \"The displays must be aligned at their top in System Preferences > Display > Arrangement!...\" as critical" >/dev/null
fi

cleanup
```

---

**Notes:**

Change the *fully qualified pathname* of the `cliclick` *binary executable* in the first line of *code* as applicable. I have it located at: `/usr/local/bin/cliclick`

Change the *fully qualified pathname* of the `cliclick` *binary executable* in the first line of *code* as applicable. I have it located at: `/usr/local/bin/cliclick`

The mouse pointer must be on the **Split View** you want swapped. If it is not on a **Split View**, then the application whose frontmost will have its main menu opened, without anything else happening. This is unavoidable as coded, because to determine whether or not one is on a **Space/Desktop** that is in **Split View** is beyond the scope of its current *code* due to the complexity of coding for such a scenario.

While your question mentioned **AppleScript**, nonetheless, I went with the "or solution for this without using a different window management app" approach using a *shell script* with the use of the `cliclick` *third-party utility*, as I believe basic *vanilla* **AppleScript** is not capable of doing the job and would most likely require **AppleScript-ObjC**.

I find that using [**CheatSheet**](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/?lang=en) helps me to examine all the *keyboard shortcut* assigned to any given *application*.

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown above, was tested under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

<sub>Note that I am not associated with the developers of any of the products mentioned herein, just a satisfied user of the aforementioned products.</sub>

Comment: I have it working partially and there are only two issues. It won't trigger with the basic macOS finder app. Also, it triggers on desktop 1 while trying to execute it on desktop 2 using a second monitor.

Comment: @Ryan Jones, RE: "It won't trigger with the basic macOS finder app." --  It works with **Finder** for me. See the **Notes:** _section_ regarding **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** --  RE: "Also, it triggers on desktop 1 while trying to execute it on desktop 2 using a second monitor." --  I've added a note to the answer. Note: As currently coded, this only works on systems with a single display, or if multiple displays, the display that is the primary display. -- I also changed 100 to 200 in `[ "$y" -lt 200 ] && xy="${x},200"` and updated why in the appropriate place.

Comment: Regarding the **quick action** not executing in **Finder**, In **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation** I have the following **Finder** boxes checked (Google Chrome, System Events, Terminal). I should mention that I'm using **macOS Big Sur v11.4**. RE: "Note: As currently coded, this only works on systems with a single display, or if multiple displays, the display that is the primary display." -- I appreciate the work you have done and will utilize this solution. If you get a second wind, I would appreciate code that works on both displays.

Comment: @Ryan Jones, In **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** do you have **Finder** there and checked? If not, then add it. --RE: "If you get a second wind, I would appreciate code that works on both displays." -- I have figured out how to make it work on a second display that is not the primary display by hard coding _coordinates_ to match my setup.  However, dynamically coding it may be an issue, I'll just have to research and test a dynamic coding approach. In the interim, using two **Automator** _Quick Action_ with different _code_ may be the way to go.

Comment: @Ryan Jones, Let me work on it a bit and I'll update the answer with something, if only an interim solution if a dynamically coded one eats up too much of my time.

Comment: Okay it is working after adding **Finder** to **Accessibility**. Good idea using two **Automator**Quick Actions. I'll look forward to an updated answer of some kind even if it's a tip on how you hard coded _coordinates_. My main display is on the right -- dual 1440p monitors.

Comment: @Ryan Jones, I have rewritten the answer and provided code for a single or dual display setup with tops aligned.